# Buildozer has a error; Kivy android manager is on working

Tags: android, linux, debugging, kivy, buildozer

My command:
`buildozer -v android debug`

`[@.local]$ uname -r`
5.0.0-32-generic

```
``
[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /home/username/.local/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/pyjnius-sdl2/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/pyjnius && /home/tsubasa/.local/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 setup.py build_ext -v

[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/username/.local/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 failed!

# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=myapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/home/tsubasa/.local/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LC_MEASUREMENT = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     LC_PAPER = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     LC_MONETARY = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     LANG = 'ja_JP.UTF-8'
#     GDM_LANG = 'ja_JP'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE = 'mate'
#     GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING = '0'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_VTNR = '7'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1002/keyring/ssh'
#     MANDATORY_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/mate.mandatory.path'
#     LC_NAME = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = 'c2'
#     XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/lightdm-data/tsubasa'
#     USER = 'tsubasa'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'mate'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     TEXTDOMAINDIR = '/usr/share/locale/'
#     DEFAULTS_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/mate.default.path'
#     QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME = 'qt5ct'
#     PWD = '/home/tsubasa/.local'
#     HOME = '/home/tsubasa'
#     TEXTDOMAIN = 'im-config'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '3230'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/mate:/home/tsubasa/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     MATE_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'mate'
#     QT_SCALE_FACTOR = '1'
#     LC_ADDRESS = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     LC_NUMERIC = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     CLUTTER_BACKEND = 'x11'
#     PAPERSIZE = 'a4'
#     TERM = 'xterm'
#     VTE_VERSION = '5202'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '2'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'MATE'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1002/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     LANGUAGE = 'ja_JP'
#     WINDOWID = '56623110'
#     LC_TELEPHONE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     GDMSESSION = 'mate'
#     LOGNAME = 'tsubasa'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1002/bus'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1002'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/tsubasa/.Xauthority'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
#     QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR = '0'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-mate:/etc/xdg'
#     PATH = '/home/tsubasa/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/tsubasa/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/tsubasa/.local/bin/'
#     LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     PS1 = '\\[\\e[1;44m\\][\\u@\\W]$\\[\\e[m\\] '
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/fpc:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/3103,unix/fpc:/tmp/.ICE-unix/3103'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     LC_TIME = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     _ = '/home/tsubasa/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/tsubasa/@days/0926kivy'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/tsubasa/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/tsubasa/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/tsubasa/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '31'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2`
```

`

```
main.py:
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class HelloApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HelloApp().run()
```

I would like to use my app in kivy android.
What I would like to install kivy, buildozer, and run my app in android.
My android is Motorora.

This is first time I post question in stackoverflow.
However, I always use this site and nice answer always helped me.

I apologize for my 2nd language English, so ask me if you cannot understand me.